# How to detect current url inside a view method

Tags: mithril.js

I am creating a form for an entity that needs to have some fields omitted when creating the entity, compared to when editing it. How do I do this? Should I have one form and omit the fields when building a form for create? Or is there a another way?

e.g.

```
module.exports = {
    view: function(vnode){
      // form built here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd have the form component check for a truthy property on `vnode.attrs`, maybe `vnode.attrs.editing`.

Then whenever you're using the component your higher-level components that are including it can do `m(Form, { editing : true / false })` and the form will do the right thing.

Checking the URL seems really brittle, I wouldn't recommend building that sort of logic inside a component. That belongs in a route-handler or a page-level component.

Comment: This is actually exactly what I did whilst waiting for an answer! I didn't know whether it was kosher to use `vnode.attrs` for such a reason but it solved the problem! Thanks!